# kryo serialization - Error during Java serialization

Tags: serialization, hazelcast, spring-session, kryo, spring-data-redis

My application has bunch of domain objects which get serialized into Redis store through spring-session. I'm trying to use Kryo (4.0.0) for automatic serialization without making objects explicitly serializable.

I'm getting the following error while trying to serialize objects that have not implemented `Serializable`.

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Error during Java serialization.
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.JavaSerializer.write(JavaSerializer.java:51)
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.KryoObjectSerializer.serialize(KryoObjectSerializer.java:51)
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:168)
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:129)
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:86)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:778)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:670)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:388)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:245)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:217)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
JBWEB000071: root cause

java.io.NotSerializableException: mypck.UserDomain
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.JavaSerializer.write(JavaSerializer.java:48)
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.KryoObjectSerializer.serialize(KryoObjectSerializer.java:51)
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:168)
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:129)
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:86)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:778)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:670)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:388)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:245)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:217)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

My Kryo initializer:

```
private Kryo getInstance() {
    Kryo kryo = new Kryo() { 
            @Override 
            public Serializer<?> getDefaultSerializer( final Class type ) { 
              if (AbstractPersistentCollection.class.isAssignableFrom( type )) { 
                  return new BeanSerializer( this, type );
              } else if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom( type )) {
                  return new JavaSerializer();
              } 

              return super.getDefaultSerializer( type ); 
            } 
          }; 

          kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new SerializingInstantiatorStrategy());

    return kryo;
}
```

Update 1:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Error during Java serialization.
Serialization trace:
authentication (org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl)
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.JavaSerializer.write(JavaSerializer.java:51)
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80)
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:505)
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.KryoObjectSerializer.serialize(KryoObjectSerializer.java:52)
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:168)
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:129)
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:86)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:778)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:670)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:388)
    org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:245)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:217)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
JBWEB000071: root cause

java.io.NotSerializableException: mypkg.UserDomain
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
```

Comment: There might be more in exception which is not shown here.. Can you show more ?

Comment: @theBeacon updated.

Comment: What part of 'java.io.NotSerializableException: mypck.UserDomain' don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP I'm struggling to configure kryo when I have object which is serializable and it has composite object(s) that doesn't implement serializable. In nutshell above securitycontextimpl managed by spring security and it has authentication object and that in turn has this user domain object (which doesn't implement serializable). I'm using kryo to bring implicit serialisation on objects that are getting saved in to redis session store via spring-session.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Java serializer` (cleared from exception), your Class `mypck.UserDomain` must implements `serializable` or `Externalizable`.

From Docs

> Kryo's JavaSerializer and use the standard Java Serialization instead.
>   This approach would be as slow as usual Java serialization, but would
>   make your class serialize as long as Java serialization is able to
>   serialize it. Of course, your classs should implement the **Serializable
>   or Externalizable interface as it is required by usual Java
>   serialization.**

The Reason of exception is

You might have been working on `composite object`, where `container class` is `serializable` but alteast one of  `contained class` is not `serializable`.

Kyro takes serializer of class whose object you passed to `Kryo.writeObject(...)`
 API.

Also, remove

`ryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new SerializingInstantiatorStrategy());`
will not work if object class whose object you passed in  `Kryo.readObject(...)` does not implement `serializable`

Better, remove this, now all serialising will be done by Kryo *(unified)*

```
  public Serializer<?> getDefaultSerializer( final Class type ) { 
       if (AbstractPersistentCollection.class.isAssignableFrom( type )) { 
             return new BeanSerializer( this, type );
          } else if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom( type )) {
             return new JavaSerializer();
      } 
   }
```

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I assume Kyro could auto-select the proper serialization for me (if my understanding is correct). I'm not forcing java serialization.

Comment: explained in answer

Comment: I guess you were right. Removed Instantiator and I could see SecurityContextImpl is composing these objects. SecurityContextImpl is serializable but my user domain object is not. User domain object has many objects attached to it. Some are serializable and some are not. Can you please suggest a solution? Updated error on the question.

Comment: remove javaserializer

Comment: as I mentioned, serializable implemented in securitycontextimpl provided by spring security. I can't remove it.

Comment: That is the point..kryo serializer has nothing  to do serializable interface.. that 's why I am saying let every serialization happen with kryo